# Installing an OS on an external hard drive vs a USB stick

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, kali-linux

I was going to download Kali Linux on a USB stick to use as a portable machine to learn ethical hacking, but I realized it would be a really slow machine because a USB is not meant to hold and run a whole OS. Then I realized I also have a 1 TB HDD from a previous laptop that I took apart lying around and I was wondering: if I download Kali Linux on that HDD instead, would the OS work at a faster and a much more bearable speed than installing Kali Linux on a USB stick?

Comment: The read and write speeds of both devices are not specified, and are required to provide an authoritative answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up a 'TOTALLY' separate "pc" on an external drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1343573/how-to-set-up-a-totally-separate-pc-on-an-external-drive)

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 speeds are *plenty* to run a distro from (up to 5 Gb/s theoretical max) if your hardware supports it. Distros like Tails are perfectly usable on even USB 2.0 thumb drives.

Be aware that not all USB thumb drives are created equally - cheaper ones will be slower so pay attention to the specs if that is concerning to you.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the hard drive is meant to hold operating system installs, and the flash drive isn't as much. Your HDD will be at much lower risk of data loss (when cared for properly) than the flash drive, which will die at a much quicker rate than even a SDD when used actively.